# How to Get Categories of Django Osacr product?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I have a list of product. I want to get the category(categories) it is associated with.
What i have done is :

```
        pro = [] #holds list of all the products
        for p in pro:
            for procat in p.get_categories():
                print(procat)
```

but it returns with Error:

```
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

I got the method from here [DJANGO OSCAR](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.3/_modules/oscar/apps/catalogue/abstract_models.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get an iterable object for the ManyToManyField "categories" as specified in the docs, you can try to call .all() method, e.g.:

```
for procat in p.get_categories().all():
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from oscar.core.loading import get_model
Product = get_model('catalogue', 'Product')
ProductCategory = get_model('catalogue', 'ProductCategory')
cat_ids = Product.objects.values_list('categories', flat=True)
categories = ProductCategory.objects.filter(pk__in=cat_ids)
```